# Splitting of a large XML file into small Chunks based on repeated elements

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax, vtd-xml

Consider the following XML with 500 MB data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parents>
  <process  Child ="A">...</process>
  <process  Child="B">...</process>
  <process  Child="A">...</process>
  <process  Child="C">..</process>
  <process Child=...
  </process>
 <\Parents>
```

This xml has multiple child attribute with tag "A" or "B" or other I want to create a separate XML for "A", "B", "C" or others like expamle_A.xml, example_B.xml etc. Below Code is creating separate xml foe each child attribute, means if we have 500 child attribute its creating 500 xml's.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            VTDGen v = new VTDGen();
            if (v.parseFile("C:\\..\\example.xml", true)) {
                VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
                AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
                ap.selectXPath("/Parents/child");
                int  chunk = 0;
                while (( ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
                    long frag = vn.getElementFragment();
                    (new FileOutputStream("C:\\....\\result" + chunk + ".xml")).write(vn.getXML().getBytes(), (int) frag,
                            (int) (frag >> 32));
                    chunk++;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Now the thing is i want to split the file on the basis of child attribute of same group for an instance all the child of "A" should be in example_A.xml file same way for B,C and others.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Oh Sorry really missed that part, I want to spilt the XML on the basis of Child name means expamle_A.xml should contains all the attribute of <Child ="A">...</Child>

Comment: it seems you are already using XPath. so what is the problem again ??

Comment: @sharon I am unable to group the child nodes in single file, lets say this file has 30 nodes with Child="A" so its creating 30 files for that but what i want is to be in single file.

Comment: ok now the picture is clearer, this should go into the question as "what have you tried so far"

Comment: you need to write root element header and tail into each file.

Comment: what is the attribute name that binds "A" or "B"?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author its process <process child="A">......</process>

Comment: @vtd-xml-author ya thats what i want but unable to achive it like each child file should be like for A the file should be <Parents>
  <Child ="A">...</Child><Child ="A">...</Child></Parents> for B file should be <Parents>
  <Child ="B">...</Child><Child ="B">...</Child></Parents>

Comment: <child="b"> is not a valid xml... you meant <process child="A">

Comment: You can use `vn.toRawString(VTDNav.TOKEN_ATTR_NAME)` to know the current attribute name and use true with fileoutputstream so that you won't overwrite the file each time.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author ya i meant  <process child="A">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very simple modification to your existing code. Actually there are multiple ways to do this. I am gonna just show you one of them: by explicitly comparing the attr val using VTDNav's getAttrVal methods().

```
public static void main1(String args[]) {
    try {
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (vg.parseFile("C:\\..\\example.xml", true)) {
            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
            ap.selectXPath("/Parents/process");
            int  chunk = 0;
            FileOutputStream fopsA=(new FileOutputStream("C:\\....\\resultA" + chunk + ".xml"));
            fopsA.write("<Parent>\n".getBytes());
            FileOutputStream fopsB=(new FileOutputStream("C:\\....\\resultB" + chunk + ".xml"));
            while (( ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
                long frag = vn.getElementFragment();
                int i=vn.getAttrVal("Child");
                if (i==-1) throw new NavException("unexpected result");
                if  (vn.compareTokenString(i,"A")==0){

                    fopsA.write(vn.getXML().getBytes(), (int) frag,
                        (int) (frag >> 32));

                }else if  (vn.compareTokenString(i,"B")==0){

                    fopsB.write(vn.getXML().getBytes(), (int) frag,
                            (int) (frag >> 32));
                }
                chunk++;
            }

            fopsA.write("</Parent>\n".getBytes());
            fopsB.write("</Parent>\n".getBytes());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks well explained, but the only problem is if we have 100 different attribute of child then we need to provide 100 else if condition for this like for A,B,C,D and so on to write it in different file. Does it have any generic way like where i can provide a loop to read all the attributes with A and write it in a file similarly for B,C and So on.

Comment: as you can see, there is certainly ways to automate this process... but it sounds more like your homework than mine. Agreed?